# Make two buttons hidden at start and when clicked on another button, shows the two buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys sorry for the trouble, I need help making buttons next and forward blocked through javascript at start and when I click on Read Manga button, I want it to show the back and forward buttons.

Need help strictly on javascript and not jQuery.

```
    function hide()
        {
        document.getElementById("listm").style.display = "none";
        }

    function showlist()
        {
        document.getElementById("listm").style.display = "block";
        }           

    function fimage()
        {
        document.getElementById("bimages").style.display = "hidden";
        }

    function pimage()
        {
        document.getElementById("bimages").style.display = "hidden"
        }


    <button onclick = "hide()">Read Manga</button>
    <button onclick = "showlist()">Show List</button>   

    <button id = "bimages" onclick = "pimages()";>Back</button>
    <button id = "bimages" onclick = "fimages();">Forward</button>

    <script>
    mangaimage = document.getElementById("mangaim");
    mangasummary = document.getElementById("ms");
    readmanga = document.getElementById("rm");
    aimages = document.getElementById("bimages");

    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with Java programming? Why the Java tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visible` is not a valid value for the `display` property (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) either do this:

```
document.getElementById("listm").style.display = "block";
```

or this:

```
document.getElementById("listm").style.visibility = "visible";
```

depending on the css you're using to hide the element

EDIT:

To hide the next and previous buttons on page load do something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <!-- your other head elements here -->
         <style>
              #next, #prev {
                   display: none;
              }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <button onclick = "hide()">Read Manga</button>
         <button onclick = "showlist()">Show List</button>   

         <button id = "next" onclick = "pimages()";>Back</button>
         <button id = "prev" onclick = "fimages();">Forward</button>
         <script>
               //your code here
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

To hide the next and previous buttons on page load with javascript do something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById("next").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("prev").style.display = "none";
}, false);
```

I really wouldn't recommend using javascript for this though, its best to keep stylistic things in css.

Comment: Ok i fixed that problem thanks. but i want to hide the two buttons prev and next when you first initially load up the page and after when you click on read manga button, it shows the initially hidden buttons prev and next.

Comment: Add two distinct ids to the buttons (right now they both have an id of `biamges` which is invalid html) and then in the `<head>` section make a `<style>` tag and define the rules that you want on page load. I will update my answer with sample code.

Comment: However is it possible to do this through javascript? I understand that doing it in css is possible but i would prefer javascript if possible. sorry and thanks.